# How to change shortcut to have: space for Search and shift+Space for Tools?

Tags: shortcut

How to change shortcut in :
**Blender preferences ⮕ Keymap ⮕ Preferences ⮕ Spacebar Action**
I need to set:

- ***Space*** for ***Search***
- ***Shift + Space*** for ***Tool***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in the *Preferences* pop-up panel *> Keymap*, type *Search* in the *Name* field, click on the large button to assign a key to this function and press the spacebar, then save the preferences (bottom left):

[image]

Same thing for *Toolbar*:

[image]